# ¿Cómo llegó "guisar" a su significado actual partiendo de "guisa"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, verbos

@Charlie en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48409983#48409983) nos ha revelado que "guisa" tiene el mismo origen que *wise* en inglés, eso me ha hecho pensar en el verbo guisar y efectivamente viene de guisa:

> **[guisar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JrqC4Gt)**
>
> ```
> De guisa
> ```
>
> **1.** tr. Preparar los alimentos sometiéndolos a la acción del fuego.
>
> **2.** tr. Preparar los alimentos haciéndolos cocer en una salsa, después de rehogados.
>
> **3.** tr. Ordenar, componer algo.
>
> **4.** tr. desus. Cuidar, disponer, preparar. Era u. t. c. prnl.
>
> **5.** tr. desus. Adobar, escabechar o preparar las carnes o pescados para su conservación.

Entonces me pregunto cómo ha llegado *guisar* a su significado actual de cocinar alimentos partiendo de *guisa* cuyo significado es:

> **[guisa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JrgO7v6)**
>
> ```
> Del germ. *wîsa; cf. ingl. wise, al. Weise.
> ```
>
> **1.** f. Modo, manera o semejanza de algo.
>
> **2.** f. desus. Voluntad, gusto, antojo.
>
> **3.** f. desus. Clase o calidad.

Tal vez venga de preparar los alimentos de una manera (guisa) concreta pero tampoco lo veo muy claro.

Comment: Muy interesante pregunta! Me gusta consultar el diccionario etimológico de Chile. Esta es la etimología de [guisa](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?guisa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El diccionario etimológico abreviado de Corominas nos dice:

> **GUISA**, h. 1140, 'modo, manera'. Del germánico WÏSA íd.; probablemente heredado por todas las lenguas romances del latín vulgar, que lo tomaría del germánico occidental (comp. el alem. *weise*, ingl. *wise*).
>   DERIV. *Guisar* 'preparar, disponer', h. 1140; 'aderezar la comida', 1490; *guisado* 'justo, apropiado', med. S. XIII; 'manjar aderezado', S. XVI; [...].

Es decir, que en el siglo XII teníamos *guisar* como "preparar, disponer", es decir, "poner una cosa a su modo o manera". Entiendo que de aquí se derivó hacia el siglo XV la acepción de "preparar la comida". En el diccionario de Nebrija de 1495 ya se puede leer:

> Guisar manjares. condio.is.

*Condio* en latín [significa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/condio#Latin) "sazonar", así que queda claro que el verbo se usaba por entonces para "cocinar".

Vamos pues al CORDE a ver qué nos dicen los textos de la época. En textos de los siglos XIII y XIV parece que se usa exclusivamente en el sentido de "preparar, disponer":

> - *E pues que uio el Emperador aquel fecho mando guisar su flota & espidiosse de los que fincauan.* (1293)
> - *Et desque esto fue fecho, mandó guisar sus bodas para un día señalado.* (1330)

Igualmente se usa *guisado* como "aquello que "aquello que está en razón y en su punto":

> - *Ca no es guisado que en un monasterio sean omnes de dos abitos; ni de dos professiones.* (1260)

Pero hacia el siglo XV se empiezan a ver textos en los que *guisar* se sigue usando como preparar, disponer... la comida:

> - *Ansi maldixo la dueña a lançarote E ansi fizo su duelo E quia les mando guisar muj bien de comer ca los queria reçibir a muj gran honrra.* (1414)
> - *[...] porque quando los cavalleros y gente d'armas ponen gran diligencia en buscar y guisar manjares especiales y viandas esquisitas en tiempo de guerra, no pueden assí entender en los actos de fortaleça [...].* (1455)
> - *[...] e después una muy grand baxilla de plata labrada de platos y escudillas y bacines y ollas para guisar de comer, que pesava todo diez mil marcos [...].* (1498)

Así, *guisar* pasó de su sentido como "preparar" (la flota, los navíos, las bodas, etc.) a "preparar la comida" ("guisar de comer"), de ahí ya a "cocinar" y más concretamente a las acepciones actuales de "cocinar al fuego" o "cociendo los alimentos en una salsa":

> - *Un caballero dio a un criado suyo, vizcaíno, unas turmas de carnero, para que se las guisase; y, a causa de ser muy ignorante diole en un papel por escrito cómo las había de guisar.* (1565)
> - *Dejemos la fruta y comamos sendos pares de huevos, que son frescos, y por no los guisar con aceite, que dicen que es manjar del diablo, los he hecho cocer.* (1550)